# VMWare Workstation: IP address conflicts

Tags: networking, vmware

We use a "Tutorial Network" at school and I'm trying to set it up at home. I copied the four Virtual Machines (all flavors of windows), installed and up and running. However on the two windows server machines I keep getting alert messages indicating a conflict in IP address'.

Looking at the Network Adapter settings, they are all on a Custom Network (VMnet0). Nowhere can I find options to configure this network and assign IP address'.

Also, this is a "Hacking" exercise, so I can't log in to machines and configure them internally (I need to break in to them, but I need the network working before I can do that...)

**EDIT**

I tried what was suggested in the answer below:

[image]

Despite setting a DHCP lease for TutServ1 and TutServ2 they both try to connect to 192.168.0.2, resulting in conflict of IP address. Is there any way I can work around this?

**EDIT 2**

After restarting every device, resetting the Lease Table, restarting, praying and a divine intervention I now have it working.

Comment: Are we helping you do something you shouldn't be doing?

Comment: @sgtbeano, thanks for being the vigilante ;) No as a student of my university I have all the licenses necessary from Microsoft and VMWare to do this and was also suggested by my lecturer should anyone want to work from home.

Comment: Have you taken a look here -> http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net.html - VMWare virtual networking is complex, but I think you should take a look under the 'advanced networking topics' in that link.  It sounds like each adapter is configured to be bridged at the moment, you may want to look at setting them up in more isolation and if needs been spawning a quick VM to handle DNS on the isolated network.  You'd then be able to get them to boot properly and presumably add your own favorite pen testing distro to the private network for learning....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only route you may have to is to setup static DHCP leases at your router for the MAC addresses of the virtual machines. You should have access to the MACs through the Virtual Machine Settings dialogue.

Shut the VMs down. Clear any DHCP leases on the router and set some static ones. Boot the VMs back up and if you're lucky and the VMs are setup for DHCP and not static IP addresses (they should be in this scenario) then you would be able to ping them at the IPs you set in the router.

Comment: Thanks runtime05! I gave that a try, I've update my question with an image showing my config. Despite setting DHCP IP Leases, both servers still try to connect to 192.168.0.2. Can I force them to do otherwise in this case?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)